# Get menus created with menu editor?

Tags: menus, navigation

I am new to wordpress and I am creating a theme for a local company as my final project towards my college degree. They wish to use this theme as a main theme for all their wp sites and that any change in design shall be taken care of by child themes.

they requested that some subpages should have a sidebar menu and some others to have another sidebar menu.

I have made a metabox with a dropdownlist in the page editor so that I can select a menu for each page. The dropdownlist displays all registered menus that are hardcoded inside the theme but not the ones created inside the admin menu editor.

```
$menus = get_registered_nav_menus();
echo '<select>';
foreach($menus as $menu => $value){
   echo '<option value="'.$menu.'">' . $value .'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

How can I also get the menus that are created with the admin menu editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this helps :

```
function get_all_wordpress_menus(){
    return get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) ); 
}
```

get_registered_nav_menus only gets the theme's menu's and not the clients menu's.

Source : [Paulund](https://paulund.co.uk/get-all-wordpress-navigation-menus)
This returns all ID's. To get the name you can use :

```
<?php $nav_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object(ID comes here); echo $nav_menu->name; ?>
```

All menu objects have the next settings :

```
Object (
term_id => 7
name => Test menu
slug => Test menu
term_group => 0
term_taxonomy_id => 3
taxonomy => nav_menu
description =>
parent => 0
count => 6
)
```

Source : [Stanhub Display wordpress menu title](https://stanhub.com/how-to-display-wordpress-custom-menu-title/)

Comment: If this is the answer you are looking for please  flag it as an answer and let me know it worked ^^

Comment: seems this might help! now i get 4 integers that i suppose are the id of the nav menus i have created. now i just need to get the name from the id so i can display the name of the menu.

Comment: <?php $nav_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object(IDhere); echo $nav_menu->name; ?>

Comment: cheers mate! wp_get_nav_menu_object woorks like a charm! you are my hero ;)

Comment: No problems mate. Its what the stackexchange is for

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of all menus created through the WordPress menu editor, use the `wp_get_nav_menus` function.

```php
<?php
var_dump( wp_get_nav_menus() );
```